# Extends class with two parameters of super class in Java

Tags: java, abstract, extends

I am trying to write an abstract class that extends another abstract class. The super class is `Expression`:

```
public abstract class Expression {
    String expression;

    /*Empty Constructor for Expression object */
    public Expression(){
    }

    /*Constructor for Expression object with String expression*/
    public Expression(String expression){
        this.expression = new String(expression);
    }
```

and the extends class is `CompoundExpression` that has two variables from type `Expression` in it:

```
public abstract class CompoundExpression extends Expression {
    Expression firstOperand, secondOperand;

    public CompoundExpression(Expression first, Expression second){
        String strFirst = first.expression;
        String strSecond = second.expression;

        this.firstOperand = super(strFirst);
        this.secondOperand = super(strSecond);
    }
}
```

I figure I am doing it the wrong way cause it isn't working... Can someone help me understand why? And how I can do it the right way?

I thought maybe to write it this way:

```
public abstract class CompoundExpression extends Expression {

    Expression firstOperand, secondOperand;

    public CompoundExpression(Expression first, Expression second){

        this.firstOperand.expression = first.expression;
        this.secondOperand.expression = second.expression;
    }
}
```

What do you think?

Comment: You seem to be encapsulating rather than extending. Both are reasonable things to do but this is a mish-mash of the two

Comment: can you please explain where I encapsulate and where i did extends?

Comment: does [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23240881/2187042) make the difference between the two clear?

Comment: Your edit would work. Remember that the super() constructor is still called at the top of your constructor even though you haven't made it explicit. If `Expression` didn't have the `Expression()` constructor you would have to explicitly choose one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you seem to be both encapsulating and extending. Both are reasonable things to do but this is a mish-mash of the two. Which one you want depends on your specific use case so I shall explain both

## Extending

This is a parent child relationship. In this case the child **is** a parent. Such as a Cat **is** a mammel. This would be achieved as follows

```
public abstract class CompoundExpression extends Expression {


    public CompoundExpression(String first){
        super(first);
    }

    //Other methods that make this class different from the parent class
}
```

### Encapsulating

This is a "has a" relationship. For example a cat "has a" leg. In this case you do not need to use the "extends" keyword

```
public abstract class CompoundExpression{

    Expression firstOperand, secondOperand;

    public CompoundExpression(Expression first, Expression second){

        this.firstOperand = first;
        this.secondOperand = second;
    }

    //other methods to use the encapsulated Expressions
}
```

## Extending and encapsulating the same class

This has its uses but is far less common than the above two; you need to be very careful, but as you mentioned it you can both extend a class and encapsulate one or more of that class. An analogy for this might be that a FemaleCat both *is* a cat and can contain cats (in the form of kittens). When doing this always act as if it is "a coincidence" that the class you encapsulate and the class you extend are the same

This would be as follows

```
public abstract class CompoundExpression extends Expression{

    Expression firstOperand, secondOperand;

    public CompoundExpression(String myString, Expression first, Expression second){

        super(myString);
        this.firstOperand = first;
        this.secondOperand = second;
    }

    //other methods to make this class unique

}
```

As I say, I personally have never done this and it should not be considered the "default" way to encapsulation. Make sure you really know what you are doing before doing this

## Conclusion

Given that a single CompoundExpression contains 2 seperate Expressions I suspect you want an encapsulating relationship

Comment: so what i need is extending the class and also encapsulating it :D cause I want to use all the methods of the superclass and also encapsulate two instance of superclass inside the childe. that is reasonable ??

Comment: @YuvalLevy Its not out of the question, but it is highly unusual. In either case you need to consider the two actions; extending and encapsulating as seperate actions with it almost being "a coincidence" that the class you're extending is also one you're encapsulating

Comment: @YuvalLevy I've added a section on how you might achieve that, but make sure its really what you want

Comment: Both extending and encapsulating is not uncommon at all. It's simply the [composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern#Structure) (it is pretty irrelevant for that pattern whether the parent is an abstract class or an interface).

Comment: @Heuster Fair enough. I was, however, concerned the OP was sleep walking into something that would technically work but which they may not understand (extending for the sake of extending and actually just encapsulating). I've toned down the unusualness of it

Answer (score 3):

The `Expression` objects you pass to the constructor of `CompoundExpression` are created already. There is no need to call the parent constructor (and in fact, that's illegal in that place).

Replace

```
this.firstOperand = super(strFirst);
this.secondOperand = super(strSecond);
```

simply by

```
this.firstOperand = first;
this.secondOperand = second;
```

Another possibility is to construct the `Expression` objects in this constructor. Then you don't need to pass `Expression`s but simply strings:

```
public CompoundExpression(String strFirst, String strSecond){
    this.firstOperand = new Expression(strFirst);
    this.secondOperand = new Expression(strSecond);
}
```

It's all a matter of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do this:

```
this.firstOperand = super(strFirst);
this.secondOperand = super(strSecond);
```

you are calling a constructor by super (which is not possible, since super should always be first) and you are trying to use a constructor of an abstract class directly, which is also impossible.

what you need to do, is to have a class which is not abstract that will implement "Expression", and then just call it:

```
this.firstOperand = new ExpressionImpl(strFirst);
this.secondOperand = new ExpressionImpl(strSecond);
```

also, in that case, you do not need to extend Expression in your CompoundExpression class.

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I see you have a bit of confusion.
Extension is one thing. What you want I guess is another.
This is extension:

```
public class Point2D {
    int x;
    int y;

    public Point2D(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }


    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

}
```

the class `Point3D` is extending the previous one

```
public class Point3D extends Point2D{

    int z;

    public Point3D(int z, int x, int y) {
        super(x, y);
        this.z = z;
    }

    public int getZ() {
        return z;
    }

    public void setZ(int z) {
        this.z = z;
    }

}
```

You just want a simple `POJO` which is using the `Expression` class you have defined previously. Nothing more than it, just encapsulating the type you defined..

```
public abstract class CompoundExpression{

    Expression firstOperand, secondOperand;

    public CompoundExpression(Expression first, Expression second){

        this.firstOperand = new Expression(strFirst);
        this.secondOperand = new Expression(strSecond);
    }
}
```